# PyTest & Allure: Screenshot of failure in Allure report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pytest, allure

I'm trying to attach screenshots to allure reports, now I'm using this code:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True, tryfirst=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)
    return rep


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def web_browser(request):
    # Open browser:
    b = webdriver.PhantomJS()

    # Return browser instance to test case:
    yield b

    # Do teardown (this code will be executed after each test):

    if request.node.rep_call.failed:
        # Make the screen-shot if test failed:
        try:
            # Make screen-shot for Allure report:
            allure.attach(str(request.function.__name__),
                          b.get_screenshot_as_png(),
                          type=AttachmentType.PNG)
        except:
            pass # just ignore

    # Close browser window:
    b.quit()
```

but it doesn't work - I can't see any screenshots in the reports when some tests failed.

I've tried:

```
allure.attach(request.function.__name__,
              b.get_screenshot_as_png(),
              type=AttachmentType.PNG)

allure.attach('screenshot' + str(uuid.uuid4()),
              b.get_screenshot_as_png(),
              type=allure.attachment_type.PNG)

allure.attach(b.get_screenshot_as_png(),
              name='screenshot',
              type=AttachmentType.PNG)

allure.attach(b.get_screenshot_as_png(),
              name='screenshot2',
              type=allure.attachment_type.PNG)
```

but nothing of this works...

Answer (score 5):

The way how I finally did it:

```
import pytest
import allure
from selenium import webdriver


@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True, tryfirst=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)
    return rep


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def web_browser(request):
    # Open browser:
    b = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/tests/phantomjs')
    b.set_window_size(1400, 1000)

    # Return browser instance to test case:
    yield b

    # Do teardown (this code will be executed after each test):

    if request.node.rep_call.failed:
        # Make the screen-shot if test failed:
        try:
            b.execute_script("document.body.bgColor = 'white';")

            allure.attach(b.get_screenshot_as_png(),
                          name=request.function.__name__,
                          attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.PNG)
        except:
            pass # just ignore

    # Close browser window:
    b.quit()
```

PyPi Libraries:

```
allure-pytest==2.3.2b1
allure-python-commons==2.3.2b1
pytest==3.4.2
```